# C++ initialize bool array

Tags: c++

I use memset to initialize bool array. But, the answer is not true. who can tell my the reason?

```
int countPrimes(int n) {
    bool *flag = new bool[n];
    int i, res = 0;
    memset(flag,false,sizeof(flag));
    for (i = 0 ; i<n ; i++) {
```

[image: Incorrect output]

Comment: Post code here, not via images or links to other sites.

Comment: Use a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Problem solved.

Comment: Or `std::vector<bool>` (despite its somewhat peculiar implementation).

Comment: Also, `memset(... false ...)`- "answer is _not true_". It's not like there are many other options left.

Comment: I'm curious which book taught you to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sizeof(flag)` has no idea about the size of the array allocated to the pointer `flag`. The size of the pointer is fixed for the architecture, meaning that only the initial part of the dynamic array would be initialized (or cause undefined behavior if `n` is small).

If you insist on using "plain" array of `bool`, change the initialization code to this:

```
memset(flags, false, sizeof(*flags)*n); // Wouldn't work with true
```

A better approach is to use `std::vector<bool>`, which uses an implementation that saves you a lot of memory compared to a "plain" array of `bool`:

```
int countPrimes(int n) {
    std::vector<bool> flag(n, false);
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        ...
    }
    return res;
}
```

Note that the use of `std::vector<bool>` frees you from having to call `delete[] flags` when you are done with the dynamically allocated array.

Comment: Or: `bool* flag = new bool[n]();` or even better, `std::unique_ptr<bool[]> flag{new bool[n]()};`

Comment: Also, any mention of `std::vector<bool>` needs to come with a warning that it does not behave like other vectors.

Comment: Sorry, -1, the `memset` option is usually wrong (assumes `sizeof(bool)==1`). `std::memset` is not `std::fill` and fills the destination with bytes (even though it accepts an `int`). C madness.

Comment: @MSalters There is absolutely, positively, **nothing** wrong with `memset`. It takes an `int` and `sizeof`, `false` gets converted to zero, and then the memory block gets filled according to the size. Period.

Comment: I really wouldn't want to explain why `memset` works with `false` and not with `true`. It's the wrong function to set an array of non-byte objects to a specific value.

Comment: @MSalters If there is any part of my answer that suggests that `memset` is somehow the right function to set an array of non-byte objects to a specific value, please point it out to me. OP posted code, I posted a simple fix, end of story.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The point would be "If you insist on plain array of bool, chage the code to `memset(...)`.". That implies the best solution is a proper container (agree), but that the #2 option is to keep the `memset`. IMO, `std::fill` would be strongly preferred to `memset`. As a rule of thumb, the third argument of `memset()` should never contain a `sizeof()`. It presumes a non-byte sized object, but applies a byte pattern.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ we'd use `std::fill` :

```
bool* flags = new bool[n];
std::fill(flags, flags+n, false); // Also works with `true`.
```

Answer (score 0):

A size of the array item is `sizeof(bool)` or equivalent `sizeof *flag`, the size of the array is `n*sizeof(bool)` or `n*sizeof *flag`, *not* `sizeof flag`. The value `sizeof flag` is most likely 4 (a size of a *pointer* type), hence 4 items of your array got set to `0` (`false`).